# Performance impact of defining multiple PHP CONSTANTS

Tags: php, constants

What will be the performance impact of defining multiple PHP CONSTANTS. I want to add all the string messages in one file. Shall I define all the strings as constants?

Comment: Store all trad in file can be great for 'static' message, but why constant ? U can create a function to get one message. Check [gettext](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php) method it s an example of trad store in files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main purpose to have `CONSTANTS` is to store your fixed value. So there is no harm in storing more values in `CONSTANT`.

If you are really worried about performance then you should store your CONSTANT in `APC cache`.

Define Constant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php

Load Defined Constants: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-load-constants.php

If we go deep one more step then you can use memcache or redis to store your strings in key value pair and fetch from there when required.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to store only 200 strings then shall I use Constants or any caching mechanism?

Comment: if its a matter of only 200 `constant` then better to use normal constants rather than any caching mechanism.